# react-piano prevActiveNotes argument return empty array, but should return the previous played notes

Tags: reactjs

The react-piano accepts a prop called onPlayNoteInput which should return the prevActiveNotes.

react-piano docs: https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-piano

```
(midiNumber, { prevActiveNotes }) => void 
function that fires whenever a play-note event is fired. Can use prevActiveNotes to record notes.
```

But the prevActiveNotes is an empty array... midiNumber is fine... but prevActiveNotes is empty..

any ideas why that might be?

This is the code:

```
  function onPlayNoteInput(midiNumber:number, { prevActiveNotes }: any) {
    console.log('prevActiveNotes: ', prevActiveNotes);
    setNotes(prevArray => [...prevArray, midiNumber])
    // console.log({notes})

  };

  return (
    <ReactPiano
      disabled={disabled}
      noteRange={noteRange}
      playNote={playNote}
      stopNote={stopNote}
      width={width}
      keyboardShortcuts={keyboardShortcuts}
      onPlayNoteInput={onPlayNoteInput}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but you have to play several notes at the same time, like a chord.